# Apple Mail shows less emails than EMLX files were imported

Tags: email, apple-mail, import-mail

I moved to another MacBook (both devices have macOS 10.14 Mojave installed). I am currently trying to import my whole Mail Library to Apple Mail on the new device by extracting each mailbox (.mbox-directory) from the old "~/Library/Mail/V6/…/".

When importing a single Mailbox via "Import Mailbox" > "Apple Mail" > selecting the .mbox-directory, the count of emails in the mailbox as shown in Apple Mail is lower than the number of .emlx-files recursively found in the .mbox-Folder.

For example, by doing `ls -R Example.mbox | grep -c .emlx` or searching in Finder for files with ".emlx" in the mailbox to be imported, it says there are 321 .emlx-files in the mailbox. When I import this mailbox to Apple Mail (as described above) and drag all mails in the imported mailbox, the small red number next to the cursor says 316. But if I drag&drop these Mails to an empty folder in the Finder, it has 321 elements.

Why does Apple Mail not show these 5 Mails, although they seem to be imported as well?

Comment: Try to locate these 5 emails and see why they're different.

Answer (score 0):

there are probably duplicate emails in your 'emlx' file archive (~/Library/Mail/V6/…/) that Mail.app crushes into a single msg.

I'm testing some app to de duplicate these emails: i.e. Emailchemy
it might be right for you. Reads the AppleMail 'elmx' archive, delete the 'emlx' duplicate and, if you want, converts the AppleMail archive to a standard format (i.e. mbox).  (https://weirdkid.com/emailchemy/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1220015)

Comment: Thanks Toto, I made the changes you recommended.